# writing code in vim editor from a python script

Tags: python, bash, vim, scripting

I am writing a python script that I run through the terminal. I want to open a python file in VIM and write code in it. I am currently using the following code which gets me to the vim file (opens it in vim editor):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python



import ctypes
import os


def is_hidden(filepath):
    name = os.path.basename(os.path.abspath(filepath))
    return (name) or (has_hidden_attribute(filepath))

def has_hidden_attribute(filepath):
    try:
        attrs = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetFileAttributesW(unicode(filepath))
        assert attrs != -1
        result = bool(attrs & 2)
    except (AttributeError, AssertionError):
        result = False
    return result

def main():
    print("found:",is_hidden('~/.jupyter'))

    #write cd ~/.jupyter in bash terminal
    os.system('~/.jupyter') #change to be ~/name
    os.system('vim file')




if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

using os.system('vim file') is opening the file in vim, and when i run the script, I am just seeing a blank file. I want to write in this blank file in the python script, then save, and exit.

how can i do this?

Comment: What is your reason for wanting to do this through vim? Why not write the file directly?

Comment: I'm just really curious if this is something that I can do. Access vim and write to it. :)

Comment: I can respect that. Unfortunately, I don't know how to help you, sorry.

Comment: You don't give enough details about what you want to do for a meaningful answer.  If you insist to do it with Vim read `:h channel.txt`, `:h if_pyth.txt`, `:h clientserver`, `:h -s`, `:h Ex-mode`.  Maybe one of these is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

First try from the command line. When that works, paste the code in python.
Write to a file with

```
vi file <<END
iThis line started with i for the insert mode.
You will need an Escape to leave the insert mode.
Difficult to write here, it will be something like ctrl-v ESC.
It will look like ^]
:wq
END
```